# Paperclip on Rails 4.0 strange warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip

I'm trying to test my controller which deal with images by paperclip. However, when I ran rspec, there are a lot of strange warnings from paperclip I guess. The warnings are look like this:

```
I, [2014-08-17T03:20:20.852108 #36314]  INFO -- : Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' 'spec/assets/images/test_banner.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
I, [2014-08-17T03:20:20.866725 #36314]  INFO -- : Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' 'spec/assets/images/test_banner.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
I, [2014-08-17T03:20:20.881726 #36314]  INFO -- : Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' 'spec/assets/images/test_banner.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
```

Can anyone tell me what are those warnings and how can I fix it?

Environment infos: Rails 4.1.4, latest paperclip, mongoid-paperclip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not warnings, they are informational statements that paperclip is logging.  You can turn paperclip's logging off for testing by adding the following in your `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
Your::Application.configure do
...
  Paperclip.options[:log] = false
...
end
```

See [Paperclip readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#logging) for further details.